# rendering a dynamic placeholder with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, placeholder

I've looked around, found several resources labeled 'ng-placeholder' or something incredibly similar. I cannot get this to work:

`<input type="text" placeholder="{{option.name}}" class="form-control" ng-switch-when="text" />`

I've noticed there doesn't appear to be anything on the [input documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) as well. I'm pretty new to angular, and this has done nothing but frustrate me for a few hours. There must be a way to do this.

Comment: maybe you can use `ng-bind` to replace current input placeholder with `{{ option.name }}`. just an idea. ;-)

Comment: @FaizShukri I tried that. For some reason, `ng-bind` put some data in the input tag itself (<input>[Object object]</input> for example) and because of that I felt like it wasn't the right way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not write your own directive for ng-placeholder? Something simple like this should work. You can call it in your html like this

```
<input ng-placeholder='test'>
```

Where test is a scope variable in the current controller.

```
.directive('ngPlaceholder', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      placeholder: '=ngPlaceholder'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.$watch('placeholder',function() {
        elem[0].placeholder = scope.placeholder;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I would have done this if it weren't so cryptic to look at. That aside, I seem to get undefined even passing in a test string (so it works, just not correctly, it seems?). Is there something I'm missing? What I did was attach this to my root module by going "myApp.directive('...' ...)"

Comment: @Seiyria That is weird, seems to work great for me. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/G32c9/)

Comment: Ohhh, I got it. It took me a bit to realize that it was a variable you had there, not a string. I'm still getting used to having to double-quote data that needs to be represented as a string (like "'String'") in some cases like radio buttons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There exists a conditional attribute property in AngularJS `ng-attr-{property_name}`

For example, I'm using different placeholders for different search terms using

```
 ng-attr-placeholder="{{isAdvanceSearch ? setPlaceholder(searchOption) : 'John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123'}}"
```

Here on the basis of `isAdvanceSearch` variable, I'm setting different placeholders in `setPlaceholder` method.

`setPlaceholder` method returns the placeholder to set in the input field.

```
$scope.setPlaceholder = function(searchOption) {
     if (searchOption === "foo") {
          return "Search by foo… e.g. foo1";
     } else if (searchOption === "bar") {
          return "Search by bar… e.g. bar123";
     } else {
          return "John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123";
     }
};
```

Note: `John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123` is the default placeholder.
Don't forget to wrap the expression in the `{{}}` brackets.