# Appending different elements to division in angular js

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs.. from Back-end I got an array like this.

Based on the "fieldType" different type of elements should be append to the "div" tag. please help me.

forms.js

```
angular.module('forms', [])

.controller('formCtrl', ["$http","$scope",
        function($http,$scope) {

        $scope.baseUrl= "http://localhost:3000";
        $scope.formName = "";
        $scope.formDescription = "";
        $scope.elements = [{
        "filedType" : "text",
        "displayName" : "Name",
        "hintText" : "Enter your name"
    },
     {
        "fieldType" : "radio",
        "displayName" : "Gender",
        "valueList" : ["Male","Femal"]
    }
    ]
}]);
```

forms.html

```
<div id="form">
  <p ng-repeat=" element in elements">

    <p ng-if="element.fieldType=='text' "> Textbox </p>

</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use ng-if inside div and check  ng-if="fieldType=='radioGroup'" then
create radio group otherwise ng-if="fieldType='textbox'" create input element

Comment: I m trying that.. something error I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code in your html

```
 <p ng-repeat=" element in elements">
    <p ng-if="element.fieldType='radioGroup'">
    radioGroup
    </p>
    <p ng-if="element.fieldType='textBox'">
    textBox
    </p>
</p>
```

and define elements like this only

```
$scope.elements = [{
        "filedType" : "textBox",
        "displayName" : "Name",
        "hintText" : "Enter your name"
    },
     {
        "fieldType" : "radioGroup",
        "displayName" : "Gender",
        "valueList" : ["Male","Femal"]
    }
    ];
```

Comment: I used ''==" in ng-if condition . Thank you.

Comment: But I am unable to access element properties inside the <p ng-if> </p>  block .why ?

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/22470325/1569443 for doing placeholder and text value